# Number sequence puzzle: strings of 0s and 1s

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

How can I solve this sequence?

011010, 100010, 100010, 100010, 000010, ?, 100010

https://free.ultimaiq.net/nse.htm

Comment: Hey Simi welcome to PSE please check my new answer as I have edited it for as much clarity as possible 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I edited this to make the answer shorter and clearer

Answer is

> 100000

Because

> In order to generate any term of the sequence. You need to first make a sequence of numbers increasing by 1 starting from 1 to infinity. Under each number place a 0 if the number is a non-prime and a 1 if it is a prime. Then to make the first term in the sequence take the first 6 digits out of that string of 1s and 0s (without altering the arrangement), to make the second term the next 6 digits (7th-12th), to make the third next 6 digits (13th-18th) and so forth.

So since

> the question mark falls on the sixth term of the sequence we need to take digits 31th-36th of the string to make the number which is **100000**

Just to make things clear with a visual representation of what’s going on:

> [image]

> Here is the number sequence of 1,2,3,4 etc over the string of 1s and 0s with the prime numbers highlighted. Notice how all of the primes are over the 1s and all the non primes are over the 0s.